# Filter a data frame based on matching values (exact) between two columns

Tags: r, dataframe, match

I have a dataframe that has two columns. One column contains list of sentences, other column contains words. For example:

```
words   sentences
loose   Loose connection several times a day on my tablet.  
loud    People don't speak loud or clear enough to hear voicemails
vice    I strongly advice you to fix this issue
advice  I strongly advice you to fix this issue
```

Now I want to filter this data frame such that I get only those rows that has words that exactly match with the words in the sentence:

```
words   sentences
loose   Loose connection several times a day on my tablet.  
loud    People don't speak loud or clear enough to hear voicemails
advice  I strongly advice you to fix this issue
```

The word 'vice' did not match exactly so it has to be removed. I have nearly 20k rows in the dataframe. Can someone suggest me which method to use to accompolish this task so that I don't lose much performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like the following:

```
df[apply(df, 1, function(x) tolower(x[1]) %in% tolower(unlist(strsplit(x[2], split='\\s+')))),]

df
   words                                                sentences
1  loose       Loose connection several times a day on my tablet.
2   loud People dont speak loud or clear enough to hear voicemail
4 advice          advice  I strongly advice you to fix this issue
```

Comment: This approach is faster than using str_detect, hence accepting this as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Using:

```
library(stringi)
df[stri_detect_regex(tolower(df$sentences), paste0('\\b',df$words,'\\b')),]
```

you get:

```
   words                                                  sentences
1  loose         Loose connection several times a day on my tablet.
2   loud People don't speak loud or clear enough to hear voicemails
4 advice                    I strongly advice you to fix this issue
```

Explanation:

- Convert the capitals in the sentences to small letter with `tolower`.
- Create a regex vector with `paste0` by wrapping the words in `words` in wordboundaries (`\\b`).
- Use `stri_detect_regex` from the stringi-package to see in wich rows there is no match, resulting in a logicalvector with `TRUE` & `FALSE` values.
- Subset with the logical vector.

As an alternative, you can also use `str_detect` from the `stringr` package (which is actually a wrapper around the `stringi` package):

```
library(stringr)
df[str_detect(tolower(df$sentences), paste0('\\b',df$words,'\\b')),]
```

---

Used data:

```
df <- structure(list(words = c("loose", "loud", "vice", "advice"), 
                     sentences = c("Loose connection several times a day on my tablet.", 
                                   "People don't speak loud or clear enough to hear voicemails", 
                                   "I strongly advice you to fix this issue", "I strongly advice you to fix this issue")), 
                .Names = c("words", "sentences"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Most simple solution is using the stringr package:

```
df<- data.frame(words=c("went","zero", "vice"), sent=c("a man went to the park","one minus one is 0","any advice?"))

df$words <- paste0(" ",df$words," ")
df$sent <- paste0(" ",df$sent," ")


df$match <- str_detect(df$sent,df$words)

df.res <- df[df$match > 0,]
df.res$match<-NULL
df.res
```

Comment: This isn't giving the preferred output on OP's data.

Comment: Working now, but it certainly isn't the most simple solution anymore imo. Moreover, the contents of the `sent` column has changed, which wasn't OP's intention.

Comment: Essentially yours is a more elegant version of mine - but i've only recently started developing my R skills myself!

Comment: It is not my intention to be hostile, but please consider the following: Judging from the desired output, a case-insensitive match is what OP is after. With regard to whether or not adding to another answer: at first you used `stri_extract` in your answer and that version of your answer wasn't giving the desired output. You switched to `str_detect` way after I posted my answer. (btw: I didn't downvote)

Comment: I was replying to someone else who since has deleted their comments, you havent been hostile at all